# JAVA Json object with '=' instead of ':'

Tags: java, json

I have a string in java, that has a JSON structure, but instead of using ':' my string uses '='. so for example I have this string:

```
[{
    index1 = val1,
    index2 = val2,
    index3 = val3&val4=inside_value
}]
```

instead of like this:

```
[{
    index1 : val1,
    index2 : val2,
    index3 : val3&val4=inside_value
}]
```

now, I can use some costume parser that I can build, but I guess there is already something that works.
any ideas please?

Comment: That's not a JSON structure at all. The already mentioned `=` is wrong, and every key and value needs to be enclosed by `"`.

Comment: What Lutz and bambam said that your example isn't valid JSON is true. Now, it depends on what you want to do with your "kindof"-JSON. If you're looking into a quick and dirty solution, then have a look at `String Replace`, where you search for all the '=' and replace them by ':'. This can be dangerous though. Remember, quick and dirty. Otherwise, have a look at what JSON is about and check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON.

Comment: @Socrates Adding the missing quotes is a little bit trickier.

Comment: Make the source send you real JSON.

Comment: @LutzHorn As mentioned, quick and dirty. Hence, not recommended for production use. But I strongly doubt that the above question aims at production use. The mentioned links should provide TheDragoner with more insight into JSON.

Comment: I thought I can get away from creating my own parser... but if not, then I will try to create something of my own... is there an easy way for creating it like a MAP object or something and then maybe a JSON?

Comment: don't write a parser for invalid JSON. Instead, create valid JSON in the first place. There is a set standard for a reason. Inventing your own slightly-different standard does not add any value. Java, like most languages, has classes already which can generate a JSON string from a Java object, and (in the opposite direction) generate a Java object from a (valid) JSON string. You can easily search for examples of what they are and how to use them.

Comment: @TheDragoner No, don't create your own parser. Check out the above links I provided to learn about JSON and how it is used. After that look for examples in Java, such as this one https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html and http://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json .

Answer (score 0):

You can go for custom parsing if the string structure is permanent

```
String convertToJson="[{"
                    +"index1 = val1,"
                    +"index2 = val2,"
                    +"index3 = val3&val4=inside_value"
                +"}]";
          String[] split1=  convertToJson.split(",");
          HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
          for(String row:split1){
              row =row.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "");
              String key=row.split("=",2)[0];
              String value=row.split("=",2)[1];
              map.put(key, value);
          }
          System.out.println("map :: "+map.toString());
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
          json.putAll( map );
          System.out.printf( "JSON:", json.toString() );
```

It is possible to create hashmap from your string by removing unwanted characters and finally create a JSONObject from the hashmap